# Magento 2 - Layered Navigation Swatches Styling

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.4.5 and would like to make edit css of the icons in the layered navigation, need them smaller and put them in rows of 6.

[image]

I cannot find where I need to add/edit the css files for this part of the website.  I tried Magento_Swatches\web\css\source_module.less  but no result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default Luma theme:

**Note:** First, you need to check the template file of the CSS source used.

You need to edit the CSS file: **swatches.css** or custom CSS if you have created one. Getting the correct element may it can give you a correct catch.

Could you adjust the width and height of the swatch div? Please remember to specify! an important rule in CSS.

```
    .swatches-globo .swatch--gl .ul-swatches-list li:not(ul.ul-globo-dropdown-option li), .globo-swatch-product-detail .swatch--gl ul.value li:not(ul.ul-globo-dropdown-option li) {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0!important;
}
```

Also,

```
 .swatches-globol .swatch--gl li .globo-size-medium, .globo-swatch-product-detail .globo-detail-size-medium {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

OR

```
.swatch-option.color {
    min-width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Thanks